# How do I figure out the installation path of apps from the Microsoft Store

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, windows-store, trello

I want to set up a hotkey tool called Autohotkey to open up a program called "Trello" when I hit a certain key combination. For that I need to know the **absolute path** of the program. The only problem is, I can't seem to figure out where it is installed, since it was **installed via the Microsoft Store**.

The code for my hotkey is supposed to look something like this:

`#t::Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Trello\trello.exe"` which causes it to run, when I hit Windows + T.

So how do I get the path for Trello?

Comment: The folder is "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" but micrsoft controls this folder and you don't have access to it. Forcing access will likely cause your apps to stop working correctly. You may want to search for the shortcut in your startmenu instead and get the path from there.

Answer (score 14):

Finding this isn't easy, but it can be done.

1. Open a PowerShell window, and make sure you're in a folder you can write to, e.g.: `cd ~\Desktop`
2. Use this command to get a dump of all your store apps and output them to a text file: `Get-AppxPackage >apps.txt`
3. Open the file in Notepad (or another text editor), and use the Find function to search for the app you're looking for
4. Look for the `InstalledLocation` field, copy the path, press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run dialog, and paste in the path. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the folder in Explorer
   [image: Find InstallLocation]
5. Look for the `AppManifest.xml` file, and open it in Notepad
6. You're now looking for two things - the package identity (circled in blue) and the application identity (in red, next to `Id`). Some packages can have more than one application, so check the `Executable` is what you'd expect
   [image: Package and Application Identities]
7. You can then start an application using a command like so:

`shell:AppsFolder\<PackageIdentity>!<ApplicationIdentity>`

**TL;DR:** try `shell:AppsFolder\45273LiamForsyth.PawsforTrello_7pb5ddty8z1pa!trello`

*Sidenote: this also works on the command line or in PowerShell by using `start <path>`*

Comment: I am trying to follow this but can't get it to work. I found the two items of information in the application manifest but could not invoke it. I am trying to find the path so I could add the application to my WindowsBlinds exclusion list.

Answer (score 6):

In windows 10 the easiest way I found is to

1. run the app
2. press Ctrl+alt+delete and open Task manager
3. go to Details
4. find there the app there
5. right click
6. choose "Open file location"

Comment: This is really nice for "regular" programs, however it doesn't work for apps from the MS store. The "go to details" is grayed out in the task manager.

Comment: Yes, it is grayed out. But you can click the > sign on the left and you should see gdbus.exe and inkscape 1.1. Right click inkscape 1.1 and select open file location

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still need this, but what I did was create a shortcut to the app on your desktop, then move the shortcut into a file somewhere, then just use the pathway to that shortcut's new location!

Comment: This is also not possible, as you cannot create for MS apps. There is no option for that.

Answer (score 0):

1. windows + r
2. open: "shell:AppsFolder" and press ok
3. find Trello and right click create shortcut
4. `#t::Run, "C:\Users\username\Desktop\trello.lnk"` should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).