# Remove Windows 10 app from fromatted drive

Tags: uninstall, reinstall, microsoft-store

So this is a very modern/MS/Metro app - Forza 7.

It has been installed on a second ssd, that had a lot of things on it, and I thought it would be easier to format it(was I wrong), and afterward just like the old times tell programs and features, that if it cant find the files, just remove it from the list.

But this is not that Windows anymore.

The game is still on the list, and when I try to launch it from MS store I get a message:

*ms-resource:Title can’t open because it cannot be found. The storage device might be missing or disconnected.*

When I try to uninstall it, it says to "try again in a bit" and gives an error code **0x80073cfa**.

So I tried a "few" things:

- I deleted the old keys for the drive from registry editor.
- Added the formatted drive to the list of drives to use for apps.
- Deleted the keys from the registry again.
- MS store reset, troubleshooting and the usual tools within Win
  itself.
- Reset the app.
- Wasn't able to find anything helpful on MS forums.
- Tried CCCleaner, Windows 10 app remover and various Powershell
  scripts.

When I search on google I usually find things to remove MS bloatware, and none of the solutions worked so far.

I want it removed from the app list so I can reinstall it, because right now I can't do that.

Resetting the whole PC or reinstalling Win wouldn't be the ideal solution, because I use this PC for various other things which would also need a reinstall and additional setting up, and this is just a game(maybe if I get a super giant, super fast m.2, then I'll reinstall).

Comment: It was internal storage, and it has been formatted, and many things installed/copied to it since, so no.
The question has absolutely nothing to do with the drive, I want the app removed from the "Apps and Features" list so I can reinstall it.

Comment: Have you tried re-selecting the (same newly formatted) device as the "device to save new apps to"? Or switching it to another drive and then back again? I am also thinking something along the lines that the Volume GUID of the drive may be the same even after format. If that were the case, I *think* that *potentially* gets changed when you repartition but not when you reformat

Comment: You might also check: ( https://superuser.com/questions/1298194/how-do-i-figure-out-the-installation-path-of-apps-from-the-microsoft-store ) for ideas about how to query and possibly change the app. That talks about `Get-AppxPackage` and I see that there is a command called `Remove-AppxPackage` have not gone through that process personally though

Comment: @D.Dan - I understand the question isn’t about the drive.  I was asking to gather the necessary information required to answer your question.  Doesn’t sound like I will be able to help you based on your last response.

Comment: @Yorik strangely it says that it's on the C:\Program Files\WindowsApps...
I think I formatted it again as F: and some id in the registry was different, then I formatted it again, but now as G: and that drive is now almost full, so reformatting it would also be painful.
And also I deleted that entry from the registry also.

Comment: @Ramhound it has been formatted and overwritten, there is nothing that can be salvaged from it.

Comment: @D.Dan - That isn’t even the direction I was going.  Don’t worry about it.  However, stop messing with the registry, you need to uninstall the application through Windows Store or a PowerShell command before doing anything.