# Automatically (on login) allow projecting to a computer via windows wireless display

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, script

I have a crappy Windows 10 laptop which I want to use as a 5th monitor for my setup. I'm essentially doing this for kicks.

I want to use the wireless display feature in windows to connect to the laptop, and I want it to run and start automatically on login - i.e. I should never have to touch the laptop beyond pressing the  power button to start it up (I've already set up auto-login).

The actual service that runs is `Receiver.exe`, but starting that process either by double clicking or from the command line results in the process starting and almost immediately dying. The program is stored in `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.PPIProjection_cw5n1h2txyewy\Receiver.exe`

It doesn't appear to be possible to make a shortcut to this program, so I can't start it using task scheduler.

Is there a way to see what the system calls in order to start it so that I can put it into a script which runs at login?

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/1298194/how-do-i-figure-out-the-installation-path-of-apps-from-the-microsoft-store) question/answer seems to be pertinent, although the command should likely be `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online` instead of `Get-AppxPackage`. That said, I can't seem to find the service's install location, because I don't know the actual feature name.

I don't really care how this gets done, I just want it to happen.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more work, I ended up just pinning the connect app to my taskbar and using autohotkey to use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to activate the app. That should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I use Project to PC on 8 very similar computers (all HP Mini's).

I recently replaced one of the HPs. After adding the Wireless Display feature to Win10 with option for "Available everywhere on secure networks", I found that the PC refused to broadcast an available Win+K connection. I could only attach by running the Connect app (pinned or unpinned).

Revisited the other 7 rooms and couldn't determine the difference... until, ah-hah, the newly provisioned machine had its Ethernet network set to Public. Switching it to Private immediately restored the broadcast.
No further need to launch the Connect app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

after doing a lot of research, i found out that if your network is Private, the cast app opens automatically;. Also I found out that in a very old version of windows 10 (version 1607). Things happen magically.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).